# Aligning text inside a Bootstrap button

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

- I noticed there are similar questions however I tried the given solutions and nothing worked *
- My custom CSS file is 100% linked correctly to the html file I'm working on *
- I'm using Bootstrap v4.3.1 *

So as the title suggests, I'm trying to align text inside a Bootstrap button - I need to do that using my own custom CSS file.

I've created my new style.css file and linked it in the header (AFTER the Bootstrap CSS link), then I added a custom class (btn1) to my Bootstrap button:

```
<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn1" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">
Launch demo modal
</button>
```

I then added the following code in my CSS:

```
.btn1{
  text-align: left !important;
}
```

But the text on the button is still not aligned to the left. Any insights as for why it happens, and ways to solve the problem?

Thanks!

Comment: The button has no defined width, so the text won't have the appearance of being aligned left. Align left relative to what?

Comment: Is there a reason you cannot use the built-in Bootstrap `text-left` class: `<button class="text-left">Button Text</button>` ? That should be your first go-to... only if that doesn't work, *then* you must manually over-ride. Also, is the button width actually wider than the button text + padding ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to change the padding on your custom css to 0, as this is still picking up the bootstrap padding. Then you can set the width to whatever size you like and add custom padding if you wanted.

Example:

```
.btn1{
  text-align: left !important;
  padding: 0;
  width: 50px;
}
```

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try this way

```
.btn.btn1{
  text-align: left;
  min-width:250px;
}
```

> note this way you don't need to add `!important`

Comment: Yeah I realised it was just a matter of adding width to the button pretty much anyway you play with it works. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Buttons in bootstrap are `inline-block` elements and do not have defined width. Therefore, `text-align: left`  does not work.

You need to specify width of it explicitly and use `align-left`. And if you need to remove event the left padding, use `pl-0`.

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container mt-5">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
      <button class="btn btn-primary pl-0">Button</button>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      <button class="btn btn-primary w-100 text-left">Button</button>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      <button class="btn btn-primary pl-0 w-100 text-left">Button</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/MMgxKz